# ASP.NET MVC add checkbox dynamically

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I have this :

```
<tr>
    <td>Label</td>
    <td>@Html.Partial("MyPartial", Model)</td>
</tr>
```

In "MyPartial" :

```
@if (Model.MyList.Count == 0){
    Html.CheckBox("chk" + Model.MyList[0].Id);

}
else
{
    Html.CheckBox("chk" + Model.MyList[0].Id); <br />
    Html.CheckBox("chkCommon"); <br />
    Html.CheckBox("chk" + Model.MyList[1].Id); <br />
}
```

I don't see any checkbox appear, when I place some text in, I see it.

Any idea ?

Thanks,

Comment: When you say "place some text in", do you mean in "MyList"? If so, are you leaving MyList null when there is no text in it, or are you instantiating an empty list e.g. `MyList = new List<SomeObject>();`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you're missing the @ in front of Html.CheckBox().

Try this:

```
    @Html.CheckBox("chk" + Model.MyList[0].Id); <br />
    @Html.CheckBox("chkCommon"); <br />
    @Html.CheckBox("chk" + Model.MyList[1].Id); <br />
```

BTW, if your list count is 0, then the block of code inside your if "true" statement will fail because you're trying to reference an item that doesn't exist in your list:

```
@if (Model.MyList.Count == 0){
    @Html.CheckBox("chk" + Model.MyList[0].Id); // will throw an exception

}
```